# Install NAS OS in data disk array instead of separate disk

Tags: raid, lvm, nas

I would like some help with my personal NAS setup.

Instead of installing the NAS OS in a separate disk, as most NAS OS documentation suggest, I am looking to install it in the data disk array instead, [the way Synology does it](https://kb.synology.com/en-us/DSM/tutorial/Which_drive_is_DSM_installed_on) for their NAS systems.

I think this makes more sense, because you would be utilizing the data disk array for redundancy, as opposed to a lone, separate disk that has none. Please correct me if I am wrong.

However, I am not sure how to do that. I thought of making a volume group for the data disk array and then making logical volumes each for the bootloader, swap, the root file system, and the NAS data, but I am not sure how to implement that or if it is the best way.

Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which NAS OS exactly you are talking about?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov I will be using OpenMediaVault, but my question should apply to any NAS OS.

Comment: The question could apply, the answer couldn't. Each distribution could have (or could not have, who knows) its own way to be installed over the RAID. The broader your question, the less probable to have the detailed and useful answer, and yours is wa-a-ay too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform [ordinary Debian installation on RAID and LVM](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/SoftwareRaidRoot) and then install OpenMediaVault in existing Debian installation [as described in the official documentation](https://docs.openmediavault.org/en/6.x/installation/on_debian.html).

Pay attention to several aspects:

- I suggest using **netinst** Debian installer, which is ISO image around 300 MiB, which is fastest way to start installation, but it will require working Internet connection *during* the installation to actually download everything.
- All disks you partition in the same way with GPT:

  - **EFI System Partition**, boot, LVM — for EFI machines. **200MiB** is enough for EFI System Partition (only around 2 MiB will be used). That's *type 1* in `fdisk` and FAT32 file system. You don't use any RAID for the ESP, because the UEFI spec authors were from stone age and never heard anything about software RAIDs, so you'll have to sync ESPs on different disks manually after bootloader updates. Also you will need to install boot records into firmware by hand with `efibootmgr` after you boot into installed system. This is needed for true redundant boot, so the system will be able to boot from any of remaining disks. Sorry, there is no ready made automation of this. One of those ESPs you mount to `/boot/efi`, for others I often create `/boot/efi-N` and mount them there.
  - **biosboot**, boot, LVM — for BIOS machines that need to boot off GPT disks. You'll need GPT if you use devices larger than 2TB, but due to the structure of the partition table `grub` needs this additional space to place its stage 1.5 code. **1 MiB** is enough, and AFAIK it should live within the first 2 TB of the device. It should have the *type 4* in `fdisk`. You don't use RAID for this either, rather you install `grub` to each disk individually. This can be done from the installer itself by repeating the bootloader installation step before last reboot, each time specifying next device name (`/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb`, etc.).
  - When installing Debian I often allocate space for both ESPs and biosboot, so the system could be changed to one boot method or another in a matter of minutes. Strictly speaking, the separate boot is not required, as GRUB knows RAID and LVM, but it makes some operations easier (recovery, disks replacement and so on).
- All **boot** partitions will be put into single RAID1 with replica on each disk (by the way, Synology DSM does it in a similar way, it creates *root* and *backup root* partitions on each disk and puts each of them into RAID1 with many copies. The way I suggest is more flexible). **200 MiB** (maybe 300) is enough, around 60 MiB will be used per kernel version, so don't forget to *purge* ancient kernels and initramfs after kernel updates. This raid device will be used for /boot file system, use ext4.
- The remaining space (almost the whole disks) you combine into single space; use many RAID1s (disks in pairs), or single RAID10 or RAID6. [Never ever use RAID5 on hard disks](https://www.askdbmgt.com/why-raid5-should-be-avoided-at-all-costs.html). Create LVM PV over that large MD RAID device (or PV on each RAID1 if you go that route). Create a VG out of it.
- Volumes for swap and root will be LVM LVs. The remaining space in the VG will be managed with OpenMediaVault. Or, you'll create data LVs in it by hand and then use them in the OpenMediaVault.

  - If you believe you'll ever use swap to hibernate the machine (I doubt it's useful for the NAS), make it slightly larger than availble RAM, otherwise **2 GiB** of **swap** is enough for any practical purposes.
  - Don't allocate too much space to **root**, that space would be wasted. **30 GiB** is more than enough for modern Debian 11 and will be enough forever.
- Don't install any graphical environment. Perform minimal install, for that in the **tasksel** only select *SSH server* and *Standard system utilities*. (The whole system will fit into 800 MiB. Isn't 30 GiB too much for root then? It is, but this is not much extra wasted space will give you extra flexibility during operations.) Everything else OpenMediaVault could require it will pull itself by its package requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've tested this structure on a VM and it seems to be working great.

My NAS, the HP StorageWorks DataVault X510, is an old but sufficiently fast Windows Home Server NAS that I will be installing OMV on.

One thing to note is that this NAS is BIOS-only. I know I should have mentioned that. I kept my question general so it can applied to anybody. How would I adapt this structure for this BIOS-only NAS, if possible?

If it's not possible, then I will be replacing this NAS with a custom-built one that supports UEFI to adopt this structure.

Comment: Also, could you elaborate on why I should never use RAID 5 on hard disks? For 4-bay NAS systems like the one I have, it seems to have the best balance of redundancy.

Comment: Thank you for including instructions for BIOS-only systems. However, I can't find the option to configure a partition as bios-boot in the Debian installer partitioner. I would do it manually, but "Execute a shell" in the installer stages gives me a minimal Busybox shell that does include any partitioning tools.

Comment: Also, do you think I could benefit from file systems other than the default ext4, like btrfs or zfs, in this kind of setup, for some or all partitions?

Comment: You can alt+F2 and use "anna-instal fdisk-udeb" to install fdisk and then partition with it. Notice this step is essential, you won't be able to boot off GPT disk with BIOS without this kind of partition. // I still don't believe BTRFS is stable enough, I only tried it once in non-very-important system and can't give any recommendations. As for ZFS, you can't use it with Debian installer. If you want to convert system to ZFS afterwards it is possible, but then you don't use LVM and MD RAID at all, and rather use ZFS's own volume manager, zvol.

Comment: One major disadvantage of ZFS is its appetite for the RAM. Don't even plan to use it on the system with less than 128 GiB of RAM *dedicated* to ZFS (not used by anything else).